# Weight of programmatically added elements in TableRow doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

So, I have a `TableLayout` with 4 `TableRow` in one xml file. I also have a xml file defining a `TextView` that will be inserted in the row (3 `TextView` per row).
I'd like those `TextView` to have the same width and that was working well when everything was in the same xml file (at the begining my `TextView` were "hard-coded") but now that I add them programmatically, they don't have the same width.

Here is the first XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/homeTable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/lmbg"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="200dp" >
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="200dp" >
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="200dp" >
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="200dp" >
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

This is my `TextView` item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="goToList"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

And finally this is how I add them programmatically

```
for(int i = 0; i < mTopCategories.size(); i++){     
    Category c = mTopCategories.get(i);
    TableRow row = ((TableRow)findViewById(rowID[idIdx])) ;
    cat = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cat_grid_item, null);
    int iconID = getResources().getIdentifier(c.getSlug().replace('-', '_'), "drawable", getPackageName());
    cat.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, iconID, 0, 0);
    int textID = getResources().getIdentifier(c.getSlug().replace('-', '_'), "string", getPackageName());
    cat.setText(textID);
    cat.setTag(c.getId().toString());
    row.addView(cat);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try explicitly setting the layout params on the TextViews like this:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams lParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, -2 /* WRAP_CONTENT */, 0.33f /* 33% of width */);
cat.setLayoutParams(lParams);
```

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html#TableRow.LayoutParams%28int,%20int,%20float%29 for more info.

Comment: Excellent solution, but for future reference, instead of -2 you can `TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this way,you even no required any xml.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);
        table.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        int id=1;
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
            tableRow.setOrientation(TableLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
                TextView textView = new TextView(this);
                textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                textView.setId(id++);
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(textView.getId()));
                textView.setTag(textView.getId());
                textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Id is : " + v.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                TableRow.LayoutParams textviewParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1f);
                textviewParams.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
                tableRow.addView(textView,textviewParams);
            }
            table.addView(tableRow,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0,1f));
        }
        setContentView(table);

    }
```